# Lock Workbench content until moderation state change

Tags: rules, workflows, workbench

I'm managing content workflow using the Workbench module. Content is moved through various states until it's made live by the publisher.

I've managed to lock content whilst it's being edited, using the Content locking module, which seems to do the job well. **However**, I now have another requirement to lock the content to the user until the user is finished editing it, which is to be indicated by changing the state to the next level, such as 'Ready for review'.

Can anybody suggest a method of doing this?

Comment: By "lock" you mean "not editable"? And it's Drupal 7, right?

Comment: I was about to say, just don't allow the user to edit their own content. They can create new content, but not edit it. Does this sound right?

Comment: Drupal 7, yes. The user may need to be able to edit their own content after it's gone through moderation and then back to draft for example.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really cool module called Rules Forms that could help here.
https://drupal.org/project/rules_forms

1. You have to set it up so that it works with your particular content type. See admin/config/workflow/rules/forms
2. Create a Rule and set two Events "XX node form is being built", and "XX node form is being validated", where XX is your content type
3. Set an Action called "Set an error on the form" and then choose "Title" for lack of something else, and then enter a message about this node being locked.
4. Set up the conditions as needed - probably need to check the user id and the state of that node - this is the part where I can't help without seeing your particular site.

If you don't set any conditions, nobody will be able to create or edit nodes of this type until you do.